# How to raise third party DLL event in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have migrated few vb6 component to dot net and below is an explanation of the issue in detail.

I have a wrapper control which references third party FarPoint control. In the wrapper control I am raising an event like below.

```
'Declaration of the event
 Public Event ButtonClicked(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
  AxFPSpreadADO._DSpreadEvents_ButtonClickedEvent) 

 'implementation of the event

Private Sub sprSpread_ButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As AxFPSpreadADO._DSpreadEvents_ButtonClickedEvent) Handles sprSpread.ButtonClicked
    RaiseEvent ButtonClicked(sender, e)
End Sub
```

So above mentioned wrapper control is referenced in one of the other component( other component is nothing but a calling component)

So in the calling component,  I have added wrapper control on the form and generated ButtonClicked event like below.

```
 Private Sub InstSpread1_ButtonClicked(Sender As Object, e As AxFPSpreadADO._DSpreadEvents_ButtonClickedEvent) Handles InstSpread1.ButtonClicked

End Sub
```

I am getting "type AxFPSpreadADO._DSpreadEvents_ButtonClickedEvent" is not defined" error and I need to refer FarPoint in the calling component as well in order to get rid of this error.

How can i raise ButtonClicked event in calling component without referring FarPoint in the calling component?

Comment: Your terminology seems to be a bit off so I want to make sure that you are approaching this in the right way.  If you are creating a wrapper then what should be happening is that you are receiving a notification from the third-party component (event or call back or whatever) and then, when that happens, you raise your own event.  Is that what you're doing?  Is `sprSpread` the third-party component that you're wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, the issue is that you are declaring your event with a third-party type for the `e` parameter:

```
Public Event ButtonClicked(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As AxFPSpreadADO._DSpreadEvents_ButtonClickedEvent)
```

What you should be doing is defining your own class that inherits `EventArgs`:

```
Public Class ButtonClickedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    '...

End Class
```

and then using that for your own event.  You could do it this way:

```
Public Event ButtonClicked(sender As System.Object, e As ButtonClickedEventArgs)
```

but you should do it this way:

```
Public Event ButtonClicked As EventHandler(Of ButtonClickedEventArgs)
```

In your own component you should then implement the event pattern fully.  That means a dedicated method to raise the event:

```
Protected Overridable Sub OnButtonClicked(e As ButtonClickedEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ButtonClicked(Me, e)
End Sub
```

In the event handler for the third-party component, you can then copy data from the `AxFPSpreadADO._DSpreadEvents_ButtonClickedEvent` object you receive into your own `ButtonClickedEventArgs` object.  I don't know what properties you need so I'll just use examples:

```
Private Sub sprSpread_ButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As AxFPSpreadADO._DSpreadEvents_ButtonClickedEvent) Handles sprSpread.ButtonClicked
    Dim eventArgs As New ButtonClickedEventArgs

    With eventArgs
        .Name = e.Name
        .Number = e.Number
    End With

    OnButtonClicked(e)
End Sub
```

EDIT:  You might also consider adding a copy constructor to your own event args class, so that you won't have to write the copy code more than once if you use it in multiple places, e.g.

```
Public Class ButtonClickedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Sub New(e As AxFPSpreadADO._DSpreadEvents_ButtonClickedEvent)
        Name = e.Name
        Number = e.Number
    End Sub

    '...

End Class
```

and then raise your event like this:

```
Private Sub sprSpread_ButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As AxFPSpreadADO._DSpreadEvents_ButtonClickedEvent) Handles sprSpread.ButtonClicked
    OnButtonClicked(New ButtonClickedEventArgs(e))
End Sub
```